# offcanvas in bootstrap 5 missing initial transition when placement is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to trigger an Offcanvas with JS and make the placement configurable.
The problem is that if I try to set the `offcanvas-end` class to the offcanvas element dynamically, the first time it is triggered, there is no transition. The second time it's fine. Is there any way to trick this into working?

```js
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')

var btnClicked = function (event) {
    myOffcanvas.className += ' offcanvas-end'
    var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
    bsOffcanvas.show()
}

document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', btnClicked)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="offcanvas" tabindex="-1" id="myOffcanvas">My offcanvas</div>

<button type="button" id="myBtn">Open</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

---

Perhaps the following snippet conveys better by aim and why I need to set the position class in JS, and not in the HTML - I want to dynamically open the offcanvas at a different position depending on the trigger element.

```js
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
var bsOffcanvas = null

var openLeftBtnClicked = function(event) {
  myOffcanvas.className = 'offcanvas offcanvas-start'
  if (bsOffcanvas) {
    bsOffcanvas.dispose()
  }
  bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas.show()
}

var openRightBtnClicked = function(event) {
  myOffcanvas.className = 'offcanvas offcanvas-end'
  if (bsOffcanvas) {
    bsOffcanvas.dispose()
  }
  bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas.show()
}

document.getElementById('openLeftBtn').addEventListener('click', openLeftBtnClicked)
document.getElementById('openRightBtn').addEventListener('click', openRightBtnClicked)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div tabindex="-1" id="myOffcanvas"></div>

<button type="button" id="openLeftBtn">Open left</button>
<button type="button" id="openRightBtn">Open right</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `offcanvas-end` class to the element itself, not via JavaScript, which will enable the animation.
It's actually `.show` class that displays it, not `offcanvas-end`.

So, you don't need to add class in your code, and it can be modified by using [`.toggle`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/#methods) method, instead of `.show`, and also you don't need to create an instance on every click, but do it before the click, and then toggle on click:

Try this:

```js
const myOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#myOffcanvas');

var btnClicked = function (event) {

    myOffcanvas.toggle();
}

document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', btnClicked);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="myOffcanvas">My offcanvas</div>

<button type="button" id="myBtn">Open</button>
```

**EDIT**

Adding class dynamically doesn't seem to work due to probably some race condition.

A workaround might be to create the element completely dynamically:

```js
var myOffcanvasContainer = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
var myOffcanvas = document.createElement('div');

myOffcanvas.textContent = 'My offcanvas';

var bsOffcanvas = null

var openLeftBtnClicked = function(event) {
  myOffcanvas.className = 'offcanvas offcanvas-start'
  if (bsOffcanvas) {
    bsOffcanvas.dispose()
  }
  
  myOffcanvasContainer.appendChild(myOffcanvas);
  
  bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas.show()
}

var openRightBtnClicked = function(event) {
  myOffcanvas.className = 'offcanvas offcanvas-end'
  if (bsOffcanvas) {
    bsOffcanvas.dispose()
  }
  
  myOffcanvasContainer.appendChild(myOffcanvas);
  
  bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas.show()
}

document.getElementById('openLeftBtn').addEventListener('click', openLeftBtnClicked)
document.getElementById('openRightBtn').addEventListener('click', openRightBtnClicked)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div tabindex="-1" id="myOffcanvas"></div>

<button type="button" id="openLeftBtn">Open left</button>
<button type="button" id="openRightBtn">Open right</button>
```

**EDIT2**

replacing the element with itself also seems to work:

```
myOffcanvas.replaceWith(myOffcanvas);
```

so I guess the browser doesn't redraw the element when it's already in the DOM and having classes changed by JS and BS offcanvas...

```js
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
var bsOffcanvas = null

var openLeftBtnClicked = function(event) {
  myOffcanvas.className = 'offcanvas offcanvas-start'
  
  myOffcanvas.replaceWith(myOffcanvas);
  
  if (bsOffcanvas) {
    bsOffcanvas.dispose()
  }
  bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas.show()
}

var openRightBtnClicked = function(event) {
  myOffcanvas.className = 'offcanvas offcanvas-end'
  
  myOffcanvas.replaceWith(myOffcanvas);
  
  if (bsOffcanvas) {
    bsOffcanvas.dispose()
  }
  bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas.show()
}

document.getElementById('openLeftBtn').addEventListener('click', openLeftBtnClicked)
document.getElementById('openRightBtn').addEventListener('click', openRightBtnClicked)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div tabindex="-1" id="myOffcanvas"></div>

<button type="button" id="openLeftBtn">Open left</button>
<button type="button" id="openRightBtn">Open right</button>
```

Comment: I have a single offcanvas div on the page, which I use to open dynamic content with ajax in. I just want its position to be dependant on the element that triggers it to show. That's why I need to set the position class in JS, not in HTML. I edited my post with another code snippet to better show what I mean .

Comment: well, that's quite different.. hm, looks like the transition animation doesn't work.. most likely it's some race condition, but can't really tell.. and forcing repaint before using `.show` doesn't make difference.. it seems to work if you create the offcanvas element dynamically, though, so I'd go that way as a workaround..

Comment: I've added the workaround, it seems to be working with completely dynamic element.. I digged around the source code, it's probably some race condition, but can't really tell..: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/offcanvas.js